# Hapijs server start error - Invalid server options

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am using this simple server program

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const server = new Hapi.Server({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8080,
});

server.route({
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  handler: (request, response) => {
    response(true);
  },
});

server.start(() => {
  console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

which gave me the following error on server startup

```
throw new Error(msgs.join(' ') || 'Unknown error');
    ^

Error: Invalid server options {
  "port" [2]: 8080,
  "host" [1]: "localhost"
}

[1] "host" is not allowed
[2] "port" is not allowed
    at Object.exports.assert (/Users/aakashverma/Documents/exercises/makeithapi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:736:11)
    at Object.exports.apply (/Users/aakashverma/Documents/exercises/makeithapi/node_modules/hapi/lib/schema.js:17:10)
    at new module.exports.internals.Server (/Users/aakashverma/Documents/exercises/makeithapi/node_modules/hapi/lib/server.js:32:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/aakashverma/Documents/exercises/makeithapi/serveEm/serveEm.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
```

and my `package.json` has dependencies set this way

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "hapi": "^16.6.2"
  }
```

I tried searching for this issue everywhere and found an exact one [here](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2267) but the versions are too old to be compared.

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options you're passing need to be passed to a call to `server.connection()` rather than into the `Server` constructor.

Snippet from [hapi docs](https://hapijs.com/tutorials):

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost' });

server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be typo issue ?
Because in their sample code [here](https://hapijs.com) they spelled server with lowercase, and you create a new instance while the sample is just using the function.

```
// Create a server with a host and port
const server = Hapi.server({ 
    host: 'localhost', 
    port: 8000 
});
```

**Update:**

Apparently, the current version for hapi is 17, and the question is asked for 16. So, the details of how to configure a server in version 16.6.2 can be found below:

https://hapijs.com/api/16.6.2

Comment: I dont think so. In the `hapi` github code I found these 2 lines `exports.Server = Server;` and 
`exports.server = Server;`

Comment: I see. Have you tried initializing the server by `Hapi.server(opts)` without the `new` keyword ?

Comment: nah, not my question though. ;-)

Comment: I have tried locally and the sample provided by hapijs works fine. Can you update question with the contents of your whole file for comparison ?

Comment: actually, the code you gave above belongs to `hapi v17.2`, the OP is using `v16.6.2`

Comment: Please provide the correct answer and not just a part of it as an update. I like how you have discussed versions, it's just that you haven't provided the code for version16.